# Java Bean and Eclipse

Tags: java, javabeans

I wrote a java program in Eclipse a couple of years ago and it was never intended to be anything other than a demo program. Now I need to release it, but I ran it out of a JtabbedPanel as a bean.

My first question is, trying to at least import the project into another Eclipse will not give me the option to run it as a bean, and I don't know how to make it so I can.

The second one is, if I figure out question one, is it possible to export a Java project that runs as a bean into a stand alone jar file to run outside of eclipse?

I dont always use Java so I'm new at this part.

Thanks

Comment: You mean the old times java beans? http://www.coderanch.com/t/106090/vc/JavaBeans-Eclipse

Comment: Yes, and I read the article, but I still don't know what to do to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read Leo's article and a few more, no bean means no main, means I write my own and instantiate things and run! How stupid of me, thanks